# Can I blow up my own mines in Code Name: S.T.E.A.M.?

Tags: code-name-steam

I have three mines set on the field with the Mine Layer. I'm not able to place any more mines until the old ones explode. Unfortunately, the enemies keep walking around my mines, and shooting the mines myself has no effect.

How do I blow up my own mines so I can set more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character that laid a mine can pick it up by walking over it. This is explained by an optional tutorial monitor in level 5-1.

[image: tutorial monitor on picking up mines]